# Getting "Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0)" error with custom code when data input increased in "History" sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I have a google sheet wherein there are 2 sheets named "Position" and "History" respectively.

I have a custom function that takes data in the "History" sheet and arrange that data in the "Position" sheet to create a portfolio of stocks with the FIFO (First in first out) method in the ticker, share and purchase column.

*Now, the problem is, everything works fine until there are fewer data in the "History" sheet, and when data is increased in the "History" sheet, the **"Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0)"** error occurs.*

**So, How to fine-tune that code to full fill the task, if not what is the possible workaround.**

**Sample sheet link:
[Click to open sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10BcyUOdx0F-CY5QD_vx9tgEAuWoqmTXgOZW284sBDjQ/edit#gid=2096216509)**

```
function generateTrade(stockQuant, stockPrice, action){
return {
shares: stockQuant,
price: stockPrice,
action: action
};
}


function generateFifo(security, actions, quantity, price){
let portfolio = new Map();
for(var i = 0; i<security.length; i++){

let ticker = security[i].toString();
let action = actions[i].toString();
let stockQuant = Number(quantity[I]);
let stockPrice = Number(price[I]);
let trade = generateTrade(stockQuant, stockPrice, action);

if(action == "Buy" || action.toUpperCase() == "DRIP"){
let activeTrades = portfolio.get(ticker);
if(activeTrades == null){
portfolio.set(ticker, [trade]);
} else {
activeTrades.push(trade);
}
}

if(action.toUpperCase() == "SPLIT"){
let activeTrades = portfolio.get(ticker);
let ratio = quantity[i].toString().split(":");
activeTrades = activeTrades.map((trade) =>{
trade.shares = trade.shares * ratio[0];
trade.price = trade.price / ratio[0];
trade.shares = trade.shares * ratio[1];
trade.price = trade.price / ratio[1];
 });
 }

if(action == "Sell"){
let activeTrades = portfolio.get(ticker);
let precision = 8;
if (activeTrades != null){
let sharesToSell = Number(Number(trade.shares).toFixed(precision));
while (sharesToSell > 0){
  sharesToSell = Number(Number(sharesToSell).toFixed(precision));
  if (activeTrades.length > 0){
    let itemToSell = activeTrades[0];
    itemToSell.shares = Number(Number(itemToSell.shares).toFixed(precision));
    if(itemToSell.shares == sharesToSell){
      sharesToSell = 0;
      activeTrades.splice(0,1);
    }

    else if(itemToSell.shares < sharesToSell){
      sharesToSell -= itemToSell.shares;
      activeTrades.splice(0,1);
    }

    else {
      itemToSell.shares -= sharesToSell;
      sharesToSell = 0;
    }
  }
}

if (activeTrades.length == 0){
  portfolio.delete(ticker);
  }
 }
 }
}
 return portfolio;
 }




     function myPositions(security, actions, quantity, price){
    let portfolio = generateFifo(security, actions, quantity, price);

   let returnArry = [];
   portfolio.forEach((value, key) => {
    let shares = 0;
   let totalCost = 0;
   let avgPrice = 0;
  value.map(trade => {
   shares += trade.shares;
  totalCost += trade.shares * trade.price;
 });

  avgPrice = totalCost / shares;
 returnArry.push([key, shares, avgPrice]);
 });

return returnArry;
}
```

**The output should come as this image:**
[image: Click to open image]

Hope I am clear to you, please help.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I suggest you to use the Format Document feature of the Google Apps Script editor to tidy up your code and make it easier to read and to use the debugger built-in function together with console.log statements. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#debugging

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets custom function have a 30 seconds execution time limit. If the time execution of your custom function depends on a growing data source it's very likely that it eventually will fail. To prevent this you have to change your approach.

You might use an installable trigger together with a control statement to automatically refresh the results when they should be updated.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score -1):

I meet this issue also, But I fixed it now.
You need to try give up use any loop like while / for
And change to use foreach()
It can fixed your problem maybe.
I can.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).